# Problems to use Array in K-means

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, k-means

a help please, I'm running the code below to do the onehotencoder of a column, then I want to pass this column to my dataset and then run K-means, but when I pass the information, I'm using tolist (), To fit the column, when running K-means I have the following problem: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. I searched a little about it, but I didn't find a definitive solution ...

I'm using 45 columns, at first I'm putting in a Dataframe, but if I had a way to put in an Array each column would be even more interesting.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=True)
SP_results_one_hot0 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,0].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot1 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,1].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot2 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,2].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot3 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,3].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot4 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,4].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot5 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,5].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot6 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,6].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot7 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,7].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot8 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,8].reshape(-1,1))
SP_results_one_hot9 = encoder.fit_transform(SP_results_Array[:,9].reshape(-1,1))



SP_results["Division Vendedor"] = SP_results_one_hot0.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["Tiempo en la Empresa"] = SP_results_one_hot1.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["Id Supervisor"] = SP_results_one_hot2.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["ID Region"] = SP_results_one_hot3.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["cargo"] = SP_results_one_hot4.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["address"] = SP_results_one_hot5.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["Idad"] = SP_results_one_hot6.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["sexo"] = SP_results_one_hot7.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["Nacion"] = SP_results_one_hot8.toarray().tolist()
SP_results["Tipo de vendedor"] = SP_results_one_hot9.toarray().tolist()


features =SP_results

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

    km = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    clusters = km.fit(features)


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling each `column` separately, you can use `get_dummies` and defines `columns` list. It will take care of it. Following is the example:

```py
import pandas as pd
col_list = ["A","B","C"]
# data is pandas dataframe
data_new = pd.get_dummies(data, col_list)
```

As `kmean` need `input` in `array` format. You can do something like this.

```py
km = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
# data_new.values will convert the dataframe to array
clusters = km.fit(data_new.values)
```

Hope this help.

Reference:

1. [pandas.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)
2. [kmean](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Do you know if it is correctly to use the columns separately for a K-means analysis? Ex. Jo type 1,2,3, I use 3 binaries columns to represent it in a dataset to use in K-mean.

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. What be careful of categorical variables. As kmean is good for numerical data. There are many ways to handle this. Following link may be helpful to you. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for, tks!